# Raise an event when button is clicked in windows forms

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I am making an user interface from windows forms (c#).In my form there are many buttons named enable (for enable each textbox).What i need to do here is when the button relevant to textbox is clicked enable the textbox.(they are not in a groupBox). Without manually coding in each button click's method how can i do this in a programmatic way

Comment: it's some thing like six buttons for six textboxes .I think you have correctly understood it .Thanks for response @Daneau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to bind a textBox's enable property to a button, I would recommend you yo build a simple custom userConrol. Inside that control you will be able to bind the logic of the button to the TextBox. You can then add any number of that specific UserControl to your application and it will automaticly bind your button's logic to the textBox.

Comment: with that method if i have 30 buttons do i have to write 30 methods?,What i tried to do is from one method catch the status change of any button in the form

Comment: With that method the logic between the button and the text box will be encapsulated inside a custom usercontrol. This means it will be like "bigger" item that contains both a TextBox AND a button and the logic between them will already be setted.   Using this usercontrol will then let you place any number you want without additionnal binding between the textbox and the button.

Comment: okay i understood that,now my problem is ,is there any method to control the things when one of six buttons clicked from one method as an example                                                                                                         if the user click button1  alert ("button1 clicked"),                                                     if the user click button2  alert ("button 2 clicked") .  Do i have to code for all the possible clicks separate?

Comment: The deeper this conversation goes the more it seems I dont understand your situation.   if the logic of the buttons is the same on all of them and you dont want to multiply the code, why don't you create a CustomButtons that inherit from Button class ? and then use this one.  The whole Custom UserControl concept was based on this. Since you want to duplicate the behavior you create a wrapper to contain this logic and then use the wrapper.